# Power BI Embed React using ServicePrincipal

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

As the title suggests, I've been trying to setup a PowerBI Embed solution using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/powerbi-client-react) here. I've managed to use the PowerBI REST API to get all the information I need (report id, access token and embed token). But for this I need an authentication token to send on the Authorization header of the request.

My question is, is there a way to use Service Principal and obtain the Authorization token that way? I've found this exact solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core) for Python and .NET, but I'm more interested in using React only for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't generate embed tokens on the client side as it is not secured.
Your solution should have a server side (Python/.NET/Java/Node.js) where you generate the embed tokens using service principal and pass it to the client side.

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem I once encountered. Generally, you can get a token using msal.js or adal.js, but you need to access the report first. To create a new inclusion token, you must create a token via Azure AD on the backend of your app.